# How to configure netty logger factory in order to see the output of LoggingHandler?

Tags: netty, slf4j

I am using slf4j logging with logback and at the beginning of my app I wrote

```
InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(new Slf4JLoggerFactory());
```

then I added to the pipeline a new `LoggingHandler(InternalLogLevel.DEBUG)` instance.
Unfortunately, this still does not log anything, I was debugging into and the debug level is the problem, just skips the logging itself.

How should I setup to get working this `LoggingHandler`?

Comment: Can you give me some more detail what the problem with DEBUG is ?

Comment: I don't see any reason why logging at DEBUG level wouldn't work.  Does logging at DEBUG level by yourself work?  If so, could you please provide us specific code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Do you have the `slf4j-api.jar` and some implementation of `sl4j` (like `logback`) in your project's classpath? You'll also need to configure the log level in the implementation specific config file (like `logback.xml` for `logback`).

Comment: Can you try putting the above line of code in `static {}` initialization code block?

Answer (score 12):

I have done a small example, that does work - I placed it on [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/4368608). It uses logback as the backend of the slf4j. The moments that should be paid attention to are:

- `InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(Slf4JLoggerFactory.INSTANCE);` should be executed right on the entry point of your program. Sometimes this "entry point" may be very hard to determine.
- Proper configuration of slf4j backend. Since slf4j is only a wrapper it does not deal with configuration at all - it is specific for log4j, logback or java.util.logging (or maybe some custom backend - I have worked heavily with the custom "java commons logging" configurator, so really anything really can be used)
- Even without LoggingHandler you should see two debug messages from static initializer of org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil (with Netty version 3.6.0.Final):

  ```
  11:54:00.959 [main] DEBUG o.j.n.c.socket.nio.SelectorUtil - Using select timeout of 500
  11:54:00.962 [main] DEBUG o.j.n.c.socket.nio.SelectorUtil - Epoll-bug workaround enabled = false
  ```

Comment: Netty however is not using my root logger, I have the following: 10:36:40,447 |-WARN in Logger[io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup] - No appenders present in context [default] for logger [io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup].

Comment: Slf4JLoggerFactory seems to be  deprecated

Comment: You need to use `InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(Slf4JLoggerFactory.INSTANCE);` instead.

Comment: Note that adding the `LoggingHandler` like `LoggingHandler(InternalLogLevel.DEBUG)` as shown in the gist will set the logger name to the FQN of the `LoggingHandler`, which is almost always never desirable. To set the logger name, pass a `Class` or `String` as the first argument.