# Netty websocket SSL connection HANDSHAKE_ISSUED

Tags: java, android, ssl, netty, handshake

I got problem with netty websocket connection while handshaking with server.

I am using it on Android.

I got event `SslHandshakeStateEvent.HANDSHAKE_ISSUED`.

What I could read is that:

`The Handshake was started but the server did not response yet to the request`.

Soon I got `channelInactive` and connection is closing.

Looks like server problem, but connection to this server works fine on other platforms such as IOS, Windows, also it works fine with other servers.

My question is that what could be wrong with this connection that I got HANDSHAKE_ISSUED, in what cases will these happen?

EDIT
Logs from netty, need to change adresses for xxx:

```
03-29 17:10:01.294 27227-27604/com.x.androidtestapp D/nativeSSL: [id: 0x3a098404] REGISTERED
03-29 17:10:01.294 27227-27604/com.x.androidtestapp D/nativeSSL: [id: 0x3a098404] CONNECT: xxx/xxx
03-29 17:10:01.594 27227-27604/com.x.androidtestapp D/nativeSSL: [id: 0x3a098404, /xxx => xxx] ACTIVE
03-29 17:10:01.604 27227-27604/com.x.androidtestapp D/nativeSSL: [id: 0x3a098404, /xxx => xxx] WRITE, DefaultFullHttpRequest(decodeResult: success)
03-29 17:10:01.604 27227-27604/com.x.androidtestapp D/nativeSSL: GET /notification/notificationChannel/websocket HTTP/1.1
03-29 17:10:01.604 27227-27604/com.x.androidtestapp D/nativeSSL: Upgrade: websocket
03-29 17:10:01.604 27227-27604/com.x.androidtestapp D/nativeSSL: Connection: Upgrade
03-29 17:10:01.604 27227-27604/com.x.androidtestapp D/nativeSSL: Sec-WebSocket-Key: K4zSElkfuBKi6ymQ1VVhuw==
03-29 17:10:01.604 27227-27604/com.x.androidtestapp D/nativeSSL: Host: xxx
03-29 17:10:01.604 27227-27604/com.x.androidtestapp D/nativeSSL: Sec-WebSocket-Origin: http://xxx
03-29 17:10:01.604 27227-27604/com.x.androidtestapp D/nativeSSL: Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13, 0B
03-29 17:10:01.604 27227-27604/com.x.androidtestapp D/nativeSSL: [id: 0x3a098404, /xxx => xxx/xxx] FLUSH
03-29 17:10:02.575 27227-27604/com.x.androidtestapp D/nativeSSL: [id: 0x3a098404, /xxx :> xxx/xxx] UNREGISTERED
```

Comment: you could start with checking ssl logs

Comment: Do netty produce own logs? Dont know how to check them, can't see anything special in log cat.

Comment: option 1 - Netty LoggingHandler http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/logging/LoggingHandler.html -  it can be added to pipeline to log everything that goes on

Comment: option 2 - enabling java ssl logs - run java with option -Djavax.net.debug=all

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Does `channel.pipeline().addLast("logger", new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG));` is enough to see ssl logs in logcat in android studio?

Comment: how about trying it yourself? in general that's enough

Comment: Asking cause I dont get logs in logcat and need to know if that is all i should do or there is anything else

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852473/how-to-configure-netty-logger-factory-in-order-to-see-the-output-of-logginghandl. Personally I used my own version netty logging handler that wrote to system out

Comment: Can't make it log anything to logcat, guess it is another question, how to do it on android.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I write my own logging handler and edit my question with logs from netty, could you help with that?

Answer (score 0):

There was unhandled 401 from http part of handshake.